# How to custom appbar style inside SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a search function with new class `extends SearchDelegate`. And I want to custom appBar `background color`, `font size`. How to achieve this?

My search class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Search extends SearchDelegate {
  final List countryList;

  Search(this.countryList);

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? countryList
        : countryList
            .where((element) =>
                element['country'].toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(query))
            .toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: Container(
            height: 70,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        suggestionList[index]['country'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Image.network(
                        suggestionList[index]['countryInfo']['flag'],
                        height: 50,
                        width: 60,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'CONFIRMED:' +
                            suggestionList[index]['cases'].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'ACTIVE:' + suggestionList[index]['active'].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'RECOVERED:' +
                            suggestionList[index]['recovered'].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'DEATHS:' + suggestionList[index]['deaths'].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                              ? Colors.grey[100]
                              : Colors.grey[900],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This class create a appbar like this

[image]

When I try to change backgound color use

```
ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color(0xff202c3b),
  );
}
```

Background color changed but some style are changed too

[image]

I want to custom a little bit style like

- Font size `bigger`
- Font color `to white`
- Don't use `underline`

How to achieve this? I can't find any `TextStyle` or something like that

**EDITED**

**CountryPage** class for use search

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:tgd_covid_tracker/pages/search.dart';

class CountryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountryPageState createState() => _CountryPageState();
}

class _CountryPageState extends State<CountryPage> {
  List countryData;

  fetchCountryData() async {
    if (this.mounted) {
      http.Response response =
          await http.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries');
      setState(() {
        countryData = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchCountryData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          countryData == null
              ? Container()
              : searchButton(
                  context,
                  countryData,
                ),
        ],
        title: Text('Country Stats'),
      ),
      body: countryData == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 200,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                countryData[index]['country'],
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              Image.network(
                                countryData[index]['countryInfo']['flag'],
                                height: 50,
                                width: 60,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'CONFIRMED:' +
                                      countryData[index]['cases'].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'ACTIVE:' +
                                      countryData[index]['active'].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'RECOVERED:' +
                                      countryData[index]['recovered']
                                          .toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'DEATHS:' +
                                      countryData[index]['deaths'].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness ==
                                            Brightness.dark
                                        ? Colors.grey[100]
                                        : Colors.grey[900],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: countryData == null ? 0 : countryData.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}

Widget searchButton(BuildContext context, countryData) {
  return IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
    onPressed: () {
      showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search(countryData));
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show us where have you implemented the appbar style in your code?

Comment: Where did you implement the search bar @Bertho Joris, please add the code

Comment: Ok wait I will update my code

Comment: Hi @Adnankarim check my update

Comment: Hi @RandomGuru check my update

Answer (score 1):

The following works flawlessly:

```dart
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        // Use this to change the query's text style
        headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        
        // Use this change the placeholder's text style
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide style to the title like this:

```
title: Text("MyApp", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight:FontWeight.w300,fontSize:20)
```

and for the underline add the following attribute

```
decoration:TextDecoration.none
```

you have to add this in AppBar() properties.

So finally:

```
title: Text("MyApp", 
  style:TextStyle(
    color:Colors.black,
    fontWeight:FontWeight.w300,
    fontSize:20,
    decoration:TextDecoration.none
  )
```

Comment: @BerthoJoris in you AppBar()

Comment: I applied in `CountryPage` class but don't change anything when I press search and show search field. Still the same

Comment: Sorry the SearchDelegate takes its style from the theme applied. I thought you were taking about AppBar(), One way to do this is by tweaking the Theme, but that wont change too much of its properties

Comment: Yes...That's what I mean. Must be inside appBarTheme right? Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the issue, and my solution won't fix the whole problem, but if what you want is just change some of the appBarTheme properties, you can do so by using the .copyWith method and indicating what are the properties that you want to override.

```
@override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement appBarTheme
    return super.appBarTheme(context).copyWith(//OVERRIDE PROPERTIES HERE);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override your appBarTheme like this :

```
@override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.black, //new AppBar color
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline6: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `appBarTheme` Method from `SearchDelegate` class for changing AppBar Theme. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html)

Examples:

```
// Default App Theme

@override
ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme.of(context);
}
```

```
// Changing AppBar color only for current AppBar

@override
ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
          color: const Color(0xff202c3b),
        ),
  );
}
```